# Why adjustSize doesn't resize MainWindow in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, resize

I have a simple application. In MainWindow's constructor I have:

```
    _someWidget = new someWidgetClass(this);
    _someWidget ->setFixedSize(700,700);
    _someWidget ->move(50,50);
   
    wid = new QWidget(this);
    wid->move(800,800);
    wid->setFixedSize(100,100);

    centralWidget()->adjustSize();
    adjustSize();
```

I would like to resize MainWindow like that, his right bottom corner should be the right bottom corner of the `wid`, so I would like to resize MainWindow to his contents. But `adjustSize` doesn't work.

I tried to add `sizeHint()` method in `someWidgetClass` and return his size, but this doesn't help too.

Comment: If you're not using Qt Layouts then you need to set all your widget sizes and positions manually. `adjustSize()` depends on layouts.  It's not clear (to me) from the example what you're ultimately trying to do. But for this particular case just set the main window size manually so that it is 900x900.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set one layout for `centralWidget` , For Example, I test it with `QGridLayout`. then add your widget in that layout :

```
 auto  _someWidget = new QWidget(this);
_someWidget->move(50, 50);
_someWidget->setFixedSize(700, 700);

centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(_someWidget);

auto  wid = new QWidget(this);
wid->move(800, 800);
wid->setFixedSize(100, 100);
centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(wid);


centralWidget()->adjustSize();
adjustSize();
```

**about adjustSize Function :**

> Adjusts the size of the widget to fit its contents. This function uses
> sizeHint() if it is valid, i.e., the size hint's width and height are
> `>= 0`. Otherwise, it sets the size to the children rectangle that covers all child widgets (the union of all child widget rectangles).
> For windows, the screen size is also taken into account. If the
> sizeHint() is less than (200, 100) and the size policy is expanding,
> the window will be at least (200, 100). The maximum size of a window
> is 2/3 of the screen's width and height.

Comment: Yes, this is possible solution, but I can't use layouts. This is only example with 2 widgets in MainWindow. Sometimes I will have more widgets and I will have to move that to target position. When I will use layouts I can only set them to right, to left or to center. But of course thank you :)

Comment: In GridLayout you can place objects anywhere you want , Read [QGridLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html). GridLayout is like a matrix , you can set where objects should be placed.

Comment: The Reason that `adjustSize` doesn't work for you is `sizeHint()`,  For windows, the screen size is also taken into account. If the sizeHint() is less than (200, 100) and the size policy is expanding, the window will be at least (200, 100). The maximum size of a window is 2/3 of the screen's width and height.

Comment: use QDebug and print your widget `sizeHint` , then you can see , is less than (200,100).

Comment: For example I have 10 widgets and they have very strange positions. QGridLayout is perfect, when widgets are in the row or column. When they aren't I have to use many spacers to set them in correct way or add to layout other layouts. So I prefer using widget->move(x,y).

Comment: But in this way , when you resize the window objects didn't resize. your window should have a fixed size. (it's not good , layout makes your app flexible)

Comment: It's true. But I would like to know how adjustSize works :)

Comment: Just fixed `sizeHint` of your widgets, In any way you like. It shouldn't be less than `(200, 100)`.                 :))

Comment: This function uses sizeHint() `if it is valid`

Comment: But how? :) I override sizeHint like that: QSize someWidgetClass::sizeHint() const
{  return size(); } and remove ```wid``` ( more easy ). In MainWindow 's constructor after setFixedSize() in _someWidget  I ```qDebug``` his sizeHint and it is ```(18, 18)```, so my override doesn't work.

Comment: It's less than (200, 100) , because of this your window size sets to (200, 100), and `adjustSize()` didn't work.

Comment: Yes, but you wrote that ```Just fixed sizeHint of your widgets, In any way you like.```, so I have to override sizeHint(), yes?

Comment: No , fixed means solve your problem by that.

Comment: I recommend layout , I don't know other ways.